# node-sass throw error when upgrade node to 4.0.0

Tags: node.js, node-sass

i'm developing an ionic app, and i use sass.
when i upgrade my node version to 4.0.0, there is an error throw out about node-sass.
the error is blow:

```
ionic $ /Applications/My-Project/nearbook/nearbooks_ionic/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22
    throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass
          ^
Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (/Applications/My-Project/nearbook/nearbooks_ionic/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/My-Project/nearbook/nearbooks_ionic/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/My-Project/nearbook/nearbooks_ionic/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

i have tried to reinstall all my node_modules (i delete node_modules folder and rerun node install) or run `node rebuild node-sass` but it still doesn't work.

when i downgrade my node version to 0.12.7 and reinstall all node_modules, my problem solved.

so i guess there is something wrong when node 4.0 compiling node-sass.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using gulp or grunt or something like that to trigger this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

make sure you're using `gulp-sass 2.0.4` by getting the newest `gulp-sass`

`npm install --save-dev gulp-sass`

and it should install its dependency on `node-sass 3.3.2` which has node 4.0 support https://twitter.com/nodesass/status/641607400651288576

Comment: This is the only correct solution. Comments in other threads say one should remove the `node_modules` directory but this is not necessary at all. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: After install `gulp-sass@`, it's throw syntax error for `bootstrap-sass-official`: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.